# The breakpoint will not be hit

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

This has got to be the most frustrating thing I've ever seen. I'm working with an asp.net web site (something I don't do often), and every once in a while, my breakpoints stop working.

About half of the time, it's because it doesn't load symbols. The other half, the source code is different from original. Deleting the solution file and re-saving the application usually fixes it, but I'm getting tired of doing that all of the time.

I've tried pretty much every solution the web has to offer, but no luck so far. Don't hold back from giving any suggestions you may have, though.

Any ideas?

Comment: Delete .net temp files, rebuild. If all else fails. Reboot

Comment: Do a complete rebuild of the project... it's just that some of the libraries are not matching with the build

Comment: @AndrewWalters trying that now. Rebooting doesn't do much for me though, as this happens every day.

Comment: @AndrewWalters deleting temp files didn't work either

Comment: Is this a web application, or a web site?  The difference is [usually] in how you open the project/solution.  In a web site, you usually do: File -> Open -> Web site.  Where as a web application you open like a normal project (File -> Open -> Project/Solution).

Comment: @CodingGorilla it's a web site. I think I may have found part of the problem. The working directory is listed as the default (documents/visual studio 2012/projects) while I've been working out of a different directory.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt Yea, if its running out of a different directory than you're coding in, that will do it! =D

Comment: @CodingGorilla didn't fix it though

Comment: Try an IIS reset?  Also, what temp files are you deleting? I usually add `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64]\[.net version]\Temproary ASP.NET Files` to my CCleaner custom include paths specifically for issues like this.

Comment: @CodingGorilla i'm using cassini. But resetting that didn't work either

Comment: @CodingGorilla if it helps, it's only happening with .aspx.cs and .ascx.cx files. Regular class files work fine.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt It's got to be some sort of caching issue, but I'm out of ideas.. =(

Comment: @CodingGorilla I figured out the issue. It was because I'm an idiot. Apparently VS was lazy-loading the symbols for codebehinds, so the breakpoints looked as if they didn't work until I requested the page. If I had spent 2 minutes actually trying to go to the page, I would have saved myself hours of trouble :P

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt Hah! I actually thought about that, but I didn't want to insult you. =)

Comment: @CodingGorilla hey, everyone could use a good insult now and again :)

Answer (score 1):

The information's about the break points (among other information's) are saved on the same directory with the solution file, in a hidden file ending in `.suo` extension.

Close the solution, find this hidden file ending in `.suo`, backup it, and then delete it from there, and then maybe you solve your problems.

This is the first that I do when I have issues with break points, and works for me.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt OK... :( I left it for the record.

Answer (score 1):

1- Check that do you have full access the folder below

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

2- If Yes close VisualStudio and delete all folders included. Clean and rebuid your project.
3- If No You need to get full access and try to delete

Answer (score 0):

A rebuild usually fixes this for me (not a build, but build -> rebuild solution). This does a full build of everything in the solution. You could also try to do a clean and build.

Comment: A Rebuild, AFAIK, doesn't actually do a clean.  It just rebuilds the entire solution without respect to projects that don't need to be built.  A normal "Build" will only build projects that [it believes] has changes.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt is the code you're trying to break on part of a user control, dll from another project in the solution that is used in code behind, etc?

Comment: @MikeCorcoran I don't think there is even a "clean" option when working with web sites

Comment: @MikeCorcoran it's the codebehind for a usercontrol (.ascx). I actually just tried it on an aspx page and it worked.

Comment: It may have to do with the fact that I checked the "load dll imports" option in tools->options

Comment: @MikeCorcoran nope, nevermind. It worked for one run-through and then I got an "access denied" for the asp.net user on a DB call. Then, upon restarting the debugger, access denied went away and breakpoints are gone again.